# multiple execution for real-time message processing

Tags: java, multithreading

I've implemented a thread pool executor on messages that are coming in real-time.

Here is some relevant example code:

```
class MessageProcessor implements SomeListener{
     StateInfo stateInfo;
     ExecutorService pool;
     MessageProcessor(StateInfo stateInfo) {
       pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);
       this.stateInfo = stateInfo;
     }
     @Override
     void processMessage(final String messageComesInRealTime) {
         Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
             if(!stateInfo.in_state) {
                 if(stateInfo.state == 1) {
                   stateInfo.in_state = true;
                   //do something with message
                   stateInfo.state = 2;
                 }
                 else if(stateInfo.state == 2) {
                  stateInfo.in_state = true;
                   //do something with message
                   stateInfo.state = 3;
                 }
                 //etc...
              }
         } 
       };
       pool.execute(runner);
       //etc...
    }
}
```

In processMessage method, messages come in real-time at a high rate and multiple messages are handled at the same time. But when stateInfo.state becomes true, I don't want other message processes to be evaluated the same way. Is it just better to remove thread altogether for this scenario? Or can there be a way around this behavior while maintaining thread execution? Thanks for any response.

Comment: I'm confused about exactly what you're doing here.  Can you succinctly elaborate?

Comment: what happens is whenever a new message comes in, the processMessage method is executed. When the rate of messages is high, sometimes 2 or more same executions are done at the same time, even if stateInfo.in_state is true. That is the only problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to synchronize access to `StateInfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you need to synchronize access and assignment to your in_state variable.

You can do this simply like so:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
//...
public void run(){
    boolean inState = false;
    synchronized(lock){
        inState = inState();
        if(inState){ setInState(false);}
    }
}
boolean inState(){
        return this.stateInfo.in_state;
}
void setInState(boolean value){
    this.stateInfo.in_state=value;
}
```

Also be sure to declare the in_state variable in StateInfo to be volatile.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm going to try this out right now and get back to you

Comment: I appreciate the accept! I wonder why he removed it... his solution was honestly better here.

Comment: @lcplusplus On reflection, I was not sure of the in order execution needs of the solution, or if the state should only be increased after processing the message.  For example, in my solution it would be possible for message 3 to trigger state 2, and message 2 to end up in state 3.  This is why I removed my solution.  The boolean state checking in the question code as posted looks to enforce essentially single threaded message processing, unless there is some additional concurrent processing that is not shown.

Comment: I found that asynchronous behavior is not really useful in this case. thanks for the response.

Comment: I agree with @lcplusplus this is an odd solution. Seems like the design needs more work.